# Google oAuth javascript to PHP - how do I get refresh and access tokens

Tags: php, redirect, google-api

Im following this tutorial here

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow

And ive gotten as far as getting the code from javascript

```
 auth2.grantOfflineAccess({
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage'
}).then(signInCallback);
 
function signInCallback(resp) {
   var auth_code = resp.code;
   console.log("AuthCode:" + auth_code)
   
   // Obviously here I want to submit the code to my PHP server to exchange it for a refresh and access token

}
```

So now that I have the response.code.   I obviously have to send it to PHP to get the access token in return.  But it seems like the PHP needs a redirect URI?? or if I use "postmessage", apparently it doesnt?

But anyway, whenever I submit the code to the server to try get an access token.  It fails with

```
     invalid grant
```

Heres my php code

```
  $client = new \Google\Client();
  $client->setAuthConfig(storage_path('/app/credentials.json'));
  $client->setAccessType("offline");
  $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
  $client->addScope(
    array(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage'
    )
  );

  $token= $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
```

$token here just returns

```
Array
(
   [error] => invalid_grant
   [error_description] => Bad Request
)
```

From what Ive been reading everywhere I HAVE to use the redirect protocol (but I really dont want to because this is a SPA app written in Vue.js and I prefereablly dont want to do redirects.  I want to send the code to the server, get the access token, store it, and use it on the server side for future requests.

How do I do this??

According to the page I was reading, it IS possible...

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow

However they only include Java and Python examples??

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up which parameters need to go where:

In the authorization request (the URL that you redirect the user to, in your case in javascript) you need to specify:

- `scope`
- `include_granted_scopes`
- `access_type=offline`
- redirect URI
- your client ID

In the token requests (where you exchange the authorization code for a token on the server) you need to specify:

- redirect URI
- authorization code
- your client ID and client secret

It's hard to say for sure what the issue is, but in your token request it looks like you're missing `redirect_uri` (the docs say you can specify an empty string if you don't have a web version of the app). It's also possible that you have mismatched Client IDs.

For your specific case, it might be worthwhile to look into managed providers that can do this for you, especially if you're building an SPA. [Xkit](https://xkit.co), where I work, is designed to work with SPAs so that you can connect the user to Google purely on the front-end and then get the (refreshed) access tokens on the back-end whenever you need them.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured it out though.  I just had to specify "postmessage" as the URI redirect in my javascript.  And on the backend as well.  This forces it not to use the redirect protocol